# Confusion about direct sums of $\mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z}$ where $p, q$ prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-sum, direct-product

I think I have some kind of fundamental misunderstanding of direct products and direct sums of groups. I'm trying to understand the following statement:

> For prime numbers $p \neq q$, we have $\mathbb{Z} / pq \mathbb{Z} = \langle \bar p \rangle \oplus \langle \bar q \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z}$. (This is a version of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.)

For some reason my brain wants the first equality to be $\mathbb{Z} / pq \mathbb{Z} \cong \langle \bar p \rangle \oplus \langle \bar q \rangle$, and the second to be $\langle \bar p \rangle \oplus \langle \bar q \rangle = \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z}$.

I've tried to construct an example by letting $p = 2$ and $q = 3$, where I believe
\begin{align}
    &\langle \bar 2 \rangle = \{ \bar 0, \bar 2, \bar 4 \} \qquad \text{and} \\
    &\langle \bar 3 \rangle = \{ \bar 0, \bar 3 \},
\end{align}
so that $\mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z} \cong \langle \bar 2 \rangle \oplus \langle \bar 3 \rangle$. I have constructed what I think is the Cayley table of $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$ —

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
+ & (0,0) & (4,3) & (2,0) & (0,3) & (4,0) & (2,3) \\ \hline
(0,0) & (0,0) & (4,3) & (2,0) & (0,3) & (4,0) & (2,3) \\ \hline
(4,3) & (4,3) & (2,0) & (0,3) & (4,0) & (2,3) & (0,0) \\ \hline
(2,0) & (2,0) & (0,3) & (4,0) & (2,3) & (0,0) & (4,3) \\ \hline
(0,3) & (0,3) & (4,0) & (2,3) & (0,0) & (4,3) & (2,0) \\ \hline
(4,0) & (4,0) & (2,3) & (0,0) & (4,3) & (2,0) & (0,3) \\ \hline
(2,3) & (2,3) & (0,0) & (4,3) & (2,0) & (0,3) & (4,0) \\ \hline
\end{array}

— as well as what I believe to be the Cayley table of $\mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z}$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{array}

If I understand it correctly, a previous theorem in the lectures notes claims that there is an isomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z}$ defined by
$$ \phi(a, b) = a + b , $$
which seems to explain the link between the two Cayley tables.

However, I've tried something similar with $p=3$ and $q=4$, and everything still works out despite $4$ not being prime?? (I realise that primeness is only a sufficient condition.) I feel like I am misunderstanding the difference between direct products and direct sums, or not calculating the groups generated by $\bar 2$ and $\bar 3$ correctly...or I haven't quite understood the $\phi$ isomorphism.

How would you explain the quoted statement above?

Comment: It all works whenever (in fact if and only if)  $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime. They do not need to be prime.

Comment: @DerekHolt What about the equality signs? Shouldn't $=$ and $\cong$ be swapped, since we're dealing with numbers versus Cartesian products of numbers?

Comment: Direct sums (and products) can be confusing, becase a direct sum can either be an external direct sum, which consists of ordered pairs of elements of the two groups, or an internal direct sum, where the factors are actually subgroups of the direct sum. The equality sign is correct if you interpret it as an internal direct sum. The second one is an ismorphism with either interpretation.